# Showing returned values in the same buffer

Tags: eval-expression

When I evaluate an expression with `C-x C-e`, I see the result returned by that expression in the minibuffer, for a while.

Can I have that returned value written in the same buffer where the evalued expression is?

How?

Comment: I removed your `buffer-local` tag. `buffer-local` in emacs is about variables having values specific to a buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The emacs way is to ask emacs:

<kbd>C-h k C-x C-e</kbd>

```
C-x C-e runs the command eval-last-sexp (found in global-map), which
is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `elisp-mode.el'.

It is bound to C-x C-e.

(eval-last-sexp EVAL-LAST-SEXP-ARG-INTERNAL)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 24.4.

Evaluate sexp before point; print value in the echo area.
Interactively, with a non `-' prefix argument, print output into
current buffer.
```

Read that last line. Do:

<kbd>C-u C-x C-e</kbd>

and observe the result.